# Auto.arima with xreg in R, restriction on forecast periods

Tags: r, time-series, forecast

I am using the `forecast` package and implement `auto.arima` with `xreg`. Here I want to forecast only for 1 year ahead but I am unable to use `h` parameter in the `forecast` function. Below is the reason for that:

> **Definition is given in manual(F1 check):**
>
> **h** = "Number of period of forecast but **if xreg is used 'h' is ignored and the forecast period will be number of rows**"

Please suggest me an alternate way to use `h` for the specific period forecast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `xreg` suggests that you have external (exogenous) variables. In this, a [regression model is fitted to the external variables with ARIMA errors](https://otexts.com/fpp2/regarima.html).

When forecasting you need to provide future values of these external variables. In practice, these are often forecasts or could be known. For example, if you're trying to predict Sales and you use Advertising spend as an external variable, you may know the advertising spend for the upcoming year.

[`auto.arima` then produces forecasts for the length of `xreg`, therefore disregarding `h`.](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.7/topics/auto.arima)

Based on your comments below, I've provided an example script demonstrating this based on the Sales example above.

```r
library(forecast)

# Generate sample data
sales <- sample(100:170, 4*10, replace = TRUE)
advertising <- sample(50:70, 4*10, replace = TRUE)

# Create time series objects.
sales_ts <- ts(sales, frequency = 4, end = c(2017, 4))


fit <- auto.arima(sales_ts, xreg = advertising)

# If we pass external_regressor into the forecast, h will be disregarded and we will
# get a forecast for length(external_regressor)

wrong_forecast = forecast(fit, h = 4, xreg = advertising)

length(wrong_forecast) # Will be 40

# To forecast four quarters in advance, we must provide forecasted external regressor data
# for the upcoming four quarters, so that length(new_regressor) == 4.
# In reality, this data is either forecasted from another forecast, or is known. We'll randomly generate it.

upcoming_advertising <- sample(50:70, 4, replace = TRUE)

correct_forecast <- forecast(fit, xreg = upcoming_advertising)

length(correct_forecast$mean) # Will be 4
```

The key things to note are:

If we forecast with the same regressors as we did when generating the forecast, `h` will be disregarded and a forecast will be generated for the length of `xreg` in your case, 10 years.

As such, we must provide new data for `xreg` for the length of time we wish to forecast - in your case, 4 quarters.

Comment: Thank you James for your response, 
1. I am using 8 years (2010-2017) of past quarterly data for training model with external variables (same length 2010-2017) data. Now I want to forecast for (4 quarters) 2018. This is where I am facing issue, Now I am trying to forecast(using 'h=4') for 4 quarters, but it is forecasting till 2025 (Next 8 years) 

2. You mentioned in your answer, "provide future values of these external variables", Which parameter shall I use to input those values.

Please clarify, it will very helpful.

Comment: Hi Zuber, in this case it sounds as though you've created your time-series object `ts` incorrectly. You can set quarterly data by setting the `frequency` parameter in `ts` to 4. For example: 

`ts(data, frequency=4, start=c(2010,1)) # First quarter of 2010.`

Comment: Hey James, I have given the frequency parameter to 4 only, attaching below code:

library(forecast)

  **TSobject = ts(NumericVec, frequency = 4, end = c(2017,4))**  # 10 years data
    
 `exreg = as.matrix(xregData)`,
 `fit = auto.arima(TSobject,  xreg = exreg)`,
`predict = forecast(fit, h = 4,  xreg = exreg)`

In the package manual, it is mention that if **'xreg'** is used, **h** will be avoided and forecast period will be the number of rows but I want to forecast only for 4 quarter.
please help me out.

Comment: I've edited my answer based on your comments with an example piece of code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, James. Your very patient person, now I got complete clarity.

Comment: James, my time series data is not having a proper trend or seasonality, I came across **ARCH and GARCH** model which works best on un-trended data. Please share the code if you have or any good link which I can refer. Just to add I have to use explanatory variables. Thank you

My mail id: `mdzubair004@gmail.com`